# After hitting the server, browser still uses a cached version

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, caching, browser, restlet

I am using **AppEngine with Restlet** to serve my data to a GWT app in the browser as client. The Restlet-GWT edition uses GWT-RPC serialization as the transport format underneath. GWT-RPC serialization relies on the **shared source** between client and server to serialize/deserialize.

Now, after **adding a new property** to one of the shared source classes, **de-serialization started failing**. The AppEngine server processed the request correctly with response HTTP 200 / OK and was sending out a correctly serialized object. The client choked each time.

After awhile I figured out that the browser was **trying to deserialize a cached copy** of my object (without the newly added property) and so de-serialization in the browswer failed.

Now the question : **why is the browser using a cached copy if the server is being hit anyhow ?**

IMO, this defeats the purpose/advantages of caching, the server and network resources are being consumed and the fresh result is not used ? In case the browswer decides to use a cached copy, I would expect no round-trip to the server.

thx !

Comment: I run into this issue when deploying a new version to AppEngine too, what are my options to prevent this from happening ?

Comment: and yes, I did stop/start the app, recompiled and all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your browser is keeping the javascript compiled by GWT for you application in cache.

Easy solution, do a hard refresh of your page a couple of times (ctrl + F5, or cmd + shift + R).

If you want to prevent this, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4274297/405492)

Comment: so the browser is caching the compiled javascript and not the payload of the XHR request ? That sounds like a valid explanation !