# HtmlUnit Only Displays Host HTML Page for GWT App

Tags: java, gwt, web-crawler, htmlunit

I am using HtmlUnit API to add crawler support to my GWT app as follows:

```java
PrintWriter out = null;
try {
    resp.setCharacterEncoding(CHAR_ENCODING);
    resp.setContentType("text/html");

    url = buildUrl(req);
    out = resp.getWriter();

    WebClient webClient = webClientProvider.get();

    // set options
    WebClientOptions options = webClient.getOptions();
    options.setCssEnabled(false);
    options.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    options.setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    options.setRedirectEnabled(true);
    options.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    // set timeouts
    webClient.setJavaScriptTimeout(0);
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(20000);

    // ajax controller
    webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());

    // render page
    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);

    webClient.getJavaScriptEngine().pumpEventLoop(timeoutMillis);

    out.println(page.asXml());

    webClient.closeAllWindows();
}
...
```

However; only the bare HTML host page for my GWT app is produced and sent to the client.

---

**UPDATE:** Here is the output from Chrome DevTools:

```
Request URL:http://127.0.0.1:8888/MyApp.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997&_escaped_fragment_=myobject%3Bid%3D507ac730e4b0e3b7a73b1b81
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:__utma=96992031.428505342.1351707614.1351707614.1356355174.2; __utmb=96992031.1.10.1356355174; __utmc=96992031; __utmz=96992031.1351707614.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
Host:127.0.0.1:8888
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11
Query String Parametersview URL encoded
gwt.codesvr:127.0.0.1:9997
_escaped_fragment_:myobject;id=507ac730e4b0e3b7a73b1b81
Response Headersview source
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Server:Jetty(6.1.x)
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

**Why isn't the GWT code being executed?**

Comment: what is error? please add error stack trace.

Comment: There are no errors.  The WebClient produces only the bare HTML host page for the GWT app.

Comment: I have added the Chrome DevTools output above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to try many variants before I finally got it to work.  One key is to leave enough time for the javascript to fully run.  But there were a few other subtleties I don't recall -- you can find below my filter version that seems to work for me, look at the parameters I set, some were keys to get this thing to work.  Other than the timer parameters that depend upon what the code to execute (and server ability to run it quickly too), it is pretty generic, so I don't understand why Google does not package such a function once and for all!

```
/**
 * Special URL token that gets passed from the crawler to the servlet filter.
 * This token is used in case there are already existing query parameters.
 */
private static final String ESCAPED_FRAGMENT_FORMAT1 = "_escaped_fragment_=";
private static final int ESCAPED_FRAGMENT_LENGTH1 = ESCAPED_FRAGMENT_FORMAT1.length();
/**
 * Special URL token that gets passed from the crawler to the servlet filter.
 * This token is used in case there are not already existing query parameters.
 */
private static final String ESCAPED_FRAGMENT_FORMAT2 = "&"+ESCAPED_FRAGMENT_FORMAT1;
private static final int ESCAPED_FRAGMENT_LENGTH2 = ESCAPED_FRAGMENT_FORMAT2.length();

private class SyncAllAjaxController extends NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Override
  public boolean processSynchron(HtmlPage page, WebRequest request, boolean async)
  {
      return true;
  }
}

private WebClient webClient = null;

private static final long _pumpEventLoopTimeoutMillis = 200;
private static final long _jsTimeoutMillis = 200;
private static final long _pageWaitMillis = 100;
final int _maxLoopChecks = 2;

public void destroy()
{
  if (webClient != null)
    webClient.closeAllWindows();
}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
    throws IOException, ServletException
{
  // Grab the request uri and query strings.
  final HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
  final String requestURI = httpRequest.getRequestURI();
  final String queryString = httpRequest.getQueryString();
  final HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

  if ((queryString != null) && (queryString.contains(ESCAPED_FRAGMENT_FORMAT1)))
  {
    // This is a Googlebot crawler request, let's return a static indexable html page
    // post javascript execution, as rendered in the browser.

    final String domain = httpRequest.getServerName();
    final int port = httpRequest.getServerPort();

    // Rewrite the URL back to the original #! version
    //   -- basically remove _escaped_fragment_ from the query. 
    // Unescape any %XX characters as need be.
    final String urlStringWithHashFragment = requestURI + rewriteQueryString(queryString);
    final String protocol = httpRequest.getProtocol();
    final URL urlWithHashFragment = new URL(protocol, domain, port, urlStringWithHashFragment);
    final WebRequest webRequest = new WebRequest(urlWithHashFragment);

    // Use the headless browser to obtain an HTML snapshot.
    webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6);
    webClient.getCache().clear();
    webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.setRedirectEnabled(false);
    webClient.setAjaxController(new SyncAllAjaxController());
    webClient.setCssErrorHandler(new SilentCssErrorHandler());

    if (_logger.isInfoEnabled())
      _logger.info("HtmlUnit starting webClient.getPage(webRequest) where webRequest = " + webRequest.toString());
    final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(webRequest);

    // Important!  Give the headless browser enough time to execute JavaScript
    // The exact time to wait may depend on your application.

    webClient.getJavaScriptEngine().pumpEventLoop(_pumpEventLoopTimeoutMillis);

    int waitForBackgroundJavaScript = webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(_jsTimeoutMillis);
    int loopCount = 0;
    while (waitForBackgroundJavaScript > 0 && loopCount < _maxLoopChecks)
    {
      ++loopCount;
      waitForBackgroundJavaScript = webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(_jsTimeoutMillis);
      if (waitForBackgroundJavaScript == 0)
      {
        if (_logger.isTraceEnabled())
          _logger.trace("HtmlUnit exits background javascript at loop counter " + loopCount);
        break;
      }
      synchronized (page) 
      {
        if (_logger.isTraceEnabled())
            _logger.trace("HtmlUnit waits for background javascript at loop counter " + loopCount);
        try
        {
          page.wait(_pageWaitMillis);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
          _logger.error("HtmlUnit ERROR on page.wait at loop counter " + loopCount);
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
    webClient.getAjaxController().processSynchron(page, webRequest, false);
    if (webClient.getJavaScriptEngine().isScriptRunning())
    {
      _logger.warn("HtmlUnit webClient.getJavaScriptEngine().shutdownJavaScriptExecutor()");
      webClient.getJavaScriptEngine().shutdownJavaScriptExecutor();
    }

    // Return the static snapshot.
    final String staticSnapshotHtml = page.asXml();
    httpResponse.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    final PrintWriter out = httpResponse.getWriter();
    out.println("<hr />");
    out.println("<center><h3>Page non-interactive pour le crawler.");
    out.println("La page interactive est: <a href=\""
        + urlWithHashFragment
        + "\">"
        + urlWithHashFragment + "</a></h3></center>");
    out.println("<hr />");
    out.println(staticSnapshotHtml);
    // Close web client.
    webClient.closeAllWindows();
    out.println("");
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    if (_logger.isInfoEnabled())
      _logger.info("HtmlUnit completed webClient.getPage(webRequest) where webRequest = " + webRequest.toString());
  }
  else
  {
    if (requestURI.contains(".nocache."))
    {
      // Ensure the gwt nocache bootstrapping file is never cached.
      // References:
      //   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274053/how-to-clear-cache-in-gwt
      //   http://seewah.blogspot.com/2009/02/gwt-tips-2-nocachejs-getting-cached-in.html
      // 
      final Date now = new Date();
      httpResponse.setDateHeader("Date", now.getTime());
      httpResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", now.getTime() - 86400000L); // One day old.
      httpResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
      httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    }

    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
  }
}

/**
 * Maps from the query string that contains _escaped_fragment_ to one that
 * doesn't, but is instead followed by a hash fragment. It also unescapes any
 * characters that were escaped by the crawler. If the query string does not
 * contain _escaped_fragment_, it is not modified.
 * 
 * @param queryString
 * @return A modified query string followed by a hash fragment if applicable.
 *         The non-modified query string otherwise.
 * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException
 */
private static String rewriteQueryString(String queryString)
    throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{
  // Seek the escaped fragment.
  int index = queryString.indexOf(ESCAPED_FRAGMENT_FORMAT2);
  int length = ESCAPED_FRAGMENT_LENGTH2;
  if (index == -1)
  {
    index = queryString.indexOf(ESCAPED_FRAGMENT_FORMAT1);
    length = ESCAPED_FRAGMENT_LENGTH1;
  }
  if (index != -1)
  {
    // Found the escaped fragment, so build back the original decoded one.
    final StringBuilder queryStringSb = new StringBuilder();
    // Add url parameters if any.
    if (index > 0)
    {
      queryStringSb.append("?");
      queryStringSb.append(queryString.substring(0, index));
    }
    // Add the hash fragment as a replacement for the escaped fragment.
    queryStringSb.append("#!");
    // Add the decoded token.
    final String token2Decode = queryString.substring(index + length, queryString.length());
    final String tokenDecoded = URLDecoder.decode(token2Decode, "UTF-8");
    queryStringSb.append(tokenDecoded);
    return queryStringSb.toString();
  }
  return queryString;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the code, Patrick.  I have tried running with your code, increased your timeouts up to 1000 fold, but its still not loading the GWT like a normal browser does.

Comment: By the way, the `SycAllAjaxController` class is not in the HtmlUnit package.  Is it custom?

Comment: I just added the few components I had missed, including SyncAllAjaxController extending from htmlunit.NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController.  It might be one of the configuration that made a difference.  Hope it does for you.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, Patrick.  I am getting a Proxy Error on my AWS server, but I'll place that in a separate question.

Comment: Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042069/servlet-filter-is-returning-proxy-error-on-aws