# The crawler escapes "mydomain#!article" into "mydomain?_escaped_fragment_=article", how to retrieve back the original url?

Tags: java, gwt

Ok, here is what Google said (https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started).

When a crawler sees a url like this `www.example.com/ajax.html#!key=value`, it will temporarily convert that url into `www.example.com/ajax.html?_escaped_fragment_=key=value`

However, when doing that it also escapes certain characters in the fragment during the transformation. Ex:
 `www.example.com/ajax.html#!key=value;car=%` to `www.example.com/ajax.html?_escaped_fragment_=key=value;car=%25`

so if we want to convert `www.example.com/ajax.html?_escaped_fragment_=key=value;car=%25` back to the original url then we need to unescape all %XX characters in the fragment.

Google said:

> Note: The crawler escapes certain characters in the fragment during
>   the transformation. To retrieve the original fragment, make sure to
>   unescape all %XX characters in the fragment. More specifically, %26
>   should become &, %20 should become a space, %23 should become #, and
>   %25 should become %, and so on.

But google doesn't say How to do that in java.

```
String originalUrl=changedStr.replace("?_escaped_fragment_=", "!#");
// then what to do next so that all the escaped characters will go back to normal?
```

Is it ok to do like this

```
originalUrl=java.net.URLDecoder.decode(originalUrl, "UTF-8");
```

Which one do we have to use: "UTF-8" or "ASCII" ?

So when the crawler escape the url, does it use URL.encode()?

if it does then which one it uses "UTF-8" or "ASCII"?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [this SO working example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997424/htmlunit-only-displays-host-html-page-for-gwt-app/14012724#14012724).  Of particular interest to you would then be the function `rewriteQueryString` at the end.

The nuts & bolts is you are on the right track, the key is to call `URLDecoder.decode`; you may also be interested in the wrapper code around it.