# After GWT Compile deployed applicatiuon does not reflect changes on server side

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, gwt, compilation

I am working on a GWT project. After having made changes server-side and compiled it useing GWT Compile, the changes are not reflected when I deploy the application on Tomcat Server. But if I run the application in dev.mode in Eclipse, the changes are reflected!

Any idea how to make the compiler use the latest code?

I have deleted all compiled filed, build and cleaned the project tons of times - none of it working.

Comment: Use JDGui class decompiler. Check whether the generated class has the code which you have modified. Then manually copy all files and try deploying it.

Comment: My Class files found in WEB-INF has the correct code. But it is still not reflected when deployed!

Comment: ..Checked using the JDGui class decompiler

Comment: It seems like it is a problem on the tomcat server. I have deployed exactly the same project in a folder with another name. Working! Is there any sort of cache on the tomcat server even though I have deleted the entire project and re-deployed it?

Answer (score 0):

This is typical if your cache settings aren't correct. Your broswer doesn't download the changed files because it has the old ones in cache and doesn't know they changed. 
Try erasing the browser cache and/or pressing ctrl-f5 in your browser.
On production systems, you need to properly configure you web server to explicitly cache GWT files matching `*.cache.*`, and explicitly NOT caching `*.nocache.*`.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997424/htmlunit-only-displays-host-html-page-for-gwt-app/14012724#14012724) for a server filter example that takes care of the cache configuration (i.e., as geert3 explained so your server does not let your browser cache an obsolete version, search for section with `requestURI.contains(".nocache.")`) and to make your app crawlable as well.