# GWT Internet Explorer Caching AJAX Responses

Tags: java, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, gwt

I have some client-server interaction and GWT is updating the webpage and making it look dynamic. This is working on Chrome and Firefox, however, IE (8,9,10) is caching the Responses. I am able to tell that its caching because I used httpwatch to view the exchange.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/USouG.png

As you can see these Responses are being cached, how can stop IE from aggressively caching like Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274053/how-to-clear-cache-in-gwt this may help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser is allowed to cache a) any GET request with b) the same url unless c) the server specifies otherwise. With those three criteria, you have three options:

- Stop using GET, and use a POST instead. This may not make sense for your use case or your server, but without any further context in your question, it is hard to be more specific
- Change the url each time the resource is requested. This 'cache-busting' strategy is often used to let the same file be loaded and not need to worry if it changed on the server or not, but to always get a fresh copy
- Specify headers from the server whether or not the file should be cached, and if so, for how long.

If you are dealing with the `<module>.nocache.js` and `<hash>.cache.html` files, these typically should get a header set on them, usually via a filter (as is mentioned in the [how to clear cache in gwt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274053/how-to-clear-cache-in-gwt) link in the comments). The `*.cache.*` files should be kept around, because their name will change automatically (see bullet #2 above), while the `*.nocache.*` should be reloaded every time, since their contents *might* have changed.